# what is wrong with this query? I am trying to update a column value based on the value of a column in a second table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

So I am trying to update the value of column `Proveedor_Logo` in table `Natan_Procesos` with the value of column `Proveedor_Logo` in table `Natan_Proveedor` where the row in table `Natan_Procesos` has a column named `Producto_Prioridad` and has a value of 1:

```
$logo = $db->query( "UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
                     SET  `Proveedor_Logo` =  `Proveedor_Logo` 
                     WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 
                     ( SELECT  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` =1 )");
```

No error appears but no value is passed either.  What am I missing?

UPDATE from replies:

so I changed it to: (with no update still)

```
$logo = $db->query( "UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
                     SET  `Proveedor_Logo` =  `Proveedor_Logo` 
                     WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 
                     ( SELECT * FROM `Natan_Procesos` WHERE `Producto_Prioridad` = 1)");
```

But I still think that there is something not right in as to where the values should be stored into. I need them to be stored into Table Natan_Procesos in column Proveedor_Logo. or where I am getting the value from?

SECOND UPDATE:

both tables have a column named Proveedor_ID that could be a second condition to match. so it would read something like this: Update column Proveedor_Logo in table Natan_Procesos where value in column Producto_Prioridad = 1 FROM column Proveedor_Logo in table Natan_Proveedor where both Natan_Proveedor and Natan_Procesos have an identical value in column Proveedor_ID

Comment: on the second select, you haven't put the complete query ( SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE ..)

Comment: please see conversation with Zack Lore below. its shaping up to where I need it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
 SET  `Proveedor_Logo` =  `Proveedor_Logo` 
 WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 
   ( SELECT `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` FROM `Natan_Procesos` WHERE `Producto_Prioridad` = 1 )"
```

---

Should it be something like this?:

```
`"UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
  SET  `Natan_Procesos`.`Proveedor_Logo` =  ( SELECT   `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_Logo` FROM `Natan_Proveedor` WHERE ?? = ?? )
  WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 1"`
```

---

Try this:

```
 UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
 INNER JOIN `Natan_Proveedor` ON
    `Natan_Procesos`.`Proveedor_ID` = `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_ID`
 SET  `Natan_Procesos`.`Proveedor_Logo` =  `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_Logo` 
 WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 1
```

Comment: that didnt work. I think the problem is somewhere in the where am I getting the info from and where I am putting it into.

Comment: you are referencing a table as a column. Natan_Procesos is a table.

Comment: I corrected that, my mistake.

So you are trying to set the value of `Natan_Procesos`.`Proveedor_Logo` =  `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_Logo` Where `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 1... is this correct?    If so, what record do you want from `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_Logo`?  Where ?? = ??

Comment: I need to copy the value in table Natan_Proveedor column Proveedor_Logo into table Natan_Procesos column Proveedor_Logo in all rows in table Natan_Procesos that have a value of 1 in column Producto_Prioridad

Comment: I tried your sugestion with the proposed where and no update still. but it reads right. See my previous reply.  Do you think I am missing a comparison of the row in table Producto_Proveedor that matches my criteria in table Natan_Procesos because table Natan_Proveedor doesnt have a column named Producto_Prioridad.

Comment: Is there a single value of `Natan_Proveedor`.`Proveedor_Logo` you are trying to set in `Natan_Procesos`?  Where an id = a certain value perhaps?  What value do you want all of the `Natan_Procesos`.`Proveddor_Logo` fields to have?

Comment: yes, both tables have a column named Proveedor_ID that could be a second condition to match. so it would read something like this:  Update column Proveedor_Logo in table Natan_Procesos where value in column Producto_Prioridad = 1 FROM column Proveedor_Logo in table Natan_Proveedor where both Natan_Proveedor and Natan_Procesos have an identical value in column Proveedor_ID

Comment: Right on spot! Thank you Zack.Lore

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a FROM and WHERE clause in the subquery.

```
$logo = $db->query( "UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
                     SET  `Proveedor_Logo` =  `Proveedor_Logo` 
                     WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 
                     ( SELECT  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` FROM ??? WHERE ??? = 1 )");
```

Comment: Don't forget to replace the FROM = ??? by your table name and WHERE ??? by the column name.

Comment: I did and still no updated column Proveedor_Logo in table Natan_Procesos

Comment: updated in my original post.  I think that my written statement is clearer than the coded one.

Comment: $logo1 = $db->query( "UPDATE  `quehago`.`Natan_Procesos` 
                     SET  `Proveedor_Logo` =  `Proveedor_Logo` 
                     WHERE  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` = 
                     ( SELECT  `Natan_Procesos`.`Producto_Prioridad` FROM `Natan_Procesos` WHERE `Producto_Prioridad` = 1 )");   BUT still no update.

Comment: Does this query return any result:
SELECT Natan_Procesos.Producto_Prioridad FROM Natan_Procesos WHERE Producto_Prioridad = 1

Comment: Please look up conversation with Zack Lore above. It is shaping up clearer with his suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the FROM & WHERE clause in your second query. Try something like this:

```
( SELECT * FROM Natan_Procesos WHERE `Producto_Prioridad` = 1);
```